# Extract column names for each value in column in matrix in R

Tags: r

I have following matrix:

```
r1 <- c("M","A","T","D","T","Y")
r2 <- c("M","A","G","G","T", "J")
r3 <- c("M","B","H","G","T", "Y")
r4 <- c("M","B","G","G","X", "Y")
r5<- c("F","A","H","D","T", "Y")
n.mat <- rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
n.mat<-as.data.frame(n.mat)
```

I would like to extract a column name for each unique value in a column as a **vector**. At the moment the column names are: `V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6`
The output should look like this:

```
V1_M V1_F V2_A V2_B V3_T V3_G V3_H V4_D V4_G V5_T V5_X V6_Y V6_J
```

The order should be in the order as the unique values occur in the column from top to bottom.

My code:

```
apply(n.mat,2,FUN = function(x) paste(unique(x), seq_along(x), sep = '_'))
```

But this converts only the values in the matrix and not the columnnames and neither outputs it as a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `paste` in a vectorized way by `rep`licating the column names with `col` index and then get the `unique` after `paste`ing with the values of the `n.mat` (it is a `data.frame` after `as.data.frame` - so we used `unlist`)

```
unique(paste(colnames(n.mat)[col(n.mat)], unlist(n.mat), sep="_"))
```

-output

```
[1] "V1_M" "V1_F" "V2_A" "V2_B" "V3_T" "V3_G" "V3_H" "V4_D"
[9] "V4_G" "V5_T" "V5_X" "V6_Y" "V6_J"
```

---

Or if need a loop, use `Map`

```
unlist(Map(function(x, y) unique(paste(y, x, sep = "_")), 
     unname(n.mat), names(n.mat)))
```

The `apply` wouldn't work here as the `names` for each column will be the row.names attribute (even if change the OP's code to `names`)

Answer (score 2):

We could use `Map` as akrun already suggested and paste the names to the values.
After that retrieve the unique values as vector:

```
n.mat[] <- Map(paste, names(n.mat), n.mat, sep = '_')
as.character(unique(unlist(n.mat)))
```

output:

```
 [1] "V1_M" "V1_F" "V2_A" "V2_B" "V3_T" "V3_G" "V3_H" "V4_D" "V4_G" "V5_T"
[11] "V5_X" "V6_Y" "V6_J"
```